How to remove large space between rows in matplotlib plot?
Code:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 6)

for row in axes:
    for ax in row:
        ## Set limits
        ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
        ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

        ## Set aspect ratio
        ax.axis('scaled')

## Plot
plt.tight_layout(pad=0.5)
plt.show()

Output:

Removing ax.axis('scaled) removes the large space between the rows, but I would like the plot to be scaled:

It is possible to adjust the spacing between the rows using figsize manually, however, getting equal spacing between the subplots has to be done by eye.

perhaps subplots_adjust

@Yarin_007 plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0) removes all the spaces between columns, but doesn't change the space between the rows.

Have a look at compressed layout https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/constrainedlayout_guide.html#grids-of-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes-compressed-layout

One way is to adapt the figsize so that it corresponds to the aspect ratio given by the subplots size and the number of rows and columns.
Assuming your subplot are squares, like here, this code modify the figsize to have an appropriate ratio, while keeping the default width.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_row, n_col = 2, 6
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_row, n_col)

fig_width = fig.get_size_inches()[0]
new_fig_height = fig_width * n_row/n_col
fig.set_size_inches(fig_width, new_fig_height)

for row in axes:
    for ax in row:
        ## Set limits
        ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
        ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)

        ## Set aspect ratio
        ax.axis('scaled')

## Plot
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



This looks right. I am surprised there isn't a matplotlib option to do this.

If I understood you correctly, maybe try this:
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n_rows = 2
n_cols = 6

fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.95, wspace=0.50, hspace=0.50)

# Percentage points of plot per Axes, width ways
ax_density = (fig.subplotpars.right - fig.subplotpars.left) / n_cols / (1 + fig.subplotpars.wspace)

# Reverse above operation in height direction to find effective subplot_adjust bottom and top delta 
plot_height = ax_density * (1 + fig.subplotpars.hspace) * n_rows

margin_h = (1 - plot_height) / 2
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=margin_h, top=1-margin_h)


for row in axes:
    for ax in row:
        ## Set limits
        ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
        ax.set_ylim(-1, 1 )

        ## Set aspect ratio
        ax.axis('scaled')

## Plot
plt.show()

I've removed plt.tight_layout() from the code, and instead parameterised subplots_adjust. Since the values in that method work using fractions of figure and axes, I've done what I think is the correct way to scale (or get close enough) to something that looks nice.

Thank you. This works, but it seems that you are left with a large top and bottom margin.

@user572780 If you want to make the window shorter, you need to change figsize (basically how user maxew has done it in their solution). I misunderstood your question, it sounded to me like you were trying to avoid changes to the figure size!
